# ot_discount module on osCommerce redeclares itself on confirmation page

Tags: php, oscommerce

On an osCommerce install with the discount code it sends the discount to PayPal fine, but when a user enters their credit card information or logs into their PayPal account to finalize the purchase, the checkout_confirmation.php page loads this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ot_discount in /home/content/36/7880936/html/twopecans/includes/modules/order_total/ot_discount.php on line 16

I've read about loading the class twice and followed some instructions to fix it but all I've gotten is a new line # or error.

Answer (score 2):

since error say redeclare it means you declare two times to get data from the new module, check your checkout_process file or any paypal_process file to get rid of the error